# Потеря введенного в консоль

Tags: c#, консоль

Привет! У меня такая проблема:
В консоль периодечески выводятся данные. Если в этот момент я печатаю - мой текст может удалиться при выводе данных. Что делать?

Comment: можно просто запомнить то, что печатается, удалить, добавить пришедшее сообщение и добавить снова то, что печаталось.

Comment: а как запомнить то, что я еще не послал в метод readline? Т.е. ввод еще на стадии печатания, как его запомнить?

Comment: придется работать с консолью более глубоко. А не просто readline. Ищите, что там есть для шарпа.

Comment: Увы, не нашел :(

Comment: попробуйте эту библиотеку http://sourceforge.net/projects/curses-sharp/

Comment: Я так понимаю, второй поток печатает по текущему положению курсора? А если сделать, чтобы он перемещал курсор на новое место, а потом возвращал его на место? Это как вариант.

Comment: KoVadim, я в общем то в англ не силен, так что не представляю возможным понять, чем мне поможет библа :(

Comment: insolor, ну меня примерно такого вида запись вход.сообщения
Console.WriteLine("сформированный мессадж"); //запись нового
Console.Write("Я>"); //создания "начала" строки для ожидания моего сообщения. 
Это все в отдельном потоке, чтобы работал цикл приема сообщений и в то же время цикл ожидания сообщения от меня

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Что-то никто не предложил ручное управление консолью. А давайте напишем, мыжпрограммисты!

Итак, дизайн таков:

1. Запись будет идти только через наш вспомогательный класс (назовём его `ConsoleEx`).
2. Поскольку у нас доступ к консоли может происходить из разных потоков, необходима блокировка.
3. Каждый объект `ConsoleEx` должен помнить свои координаты на экране.
4. Нужно понятие фокуса (на случай, если у нас есть одновременный ввод).

Пишем!

```
public class ConsoleEx
{
    static object accessToken = new object(); // блокировка
    int currX, currY;                         // текущие координаты этого объекта
    static ConsoleEx focusOwner = null;

    public ConsoleEx(int startX, int startY)
    {
        currX = startX;
        currY = startY;
    }

    // эти два метода должны вызываться под блокировкой
    void SaveCursorPosition()
    {
        currX = Console.CursorLeft;
        currY = Console.CursorTop;
    }
    void RestoreCursorPosition()
    {
        Console.SetCursorPosition(currX, currY);
    }

    // в пустом конструкторе запоминаем текущие координаты
    public ConsoleEx()
    {
        lock (accessToken)
            SaveCursorPosition();
    }

    // вспомогательный метод: выполнить действие и запомнить обновлённую позицию курсора
    // если есть фокус, отдать курсор ему
    void Execute(Action a)
    {
        lock (accessToken)
        {
            RestoreCursorPosition();
            a();
            SaveCursorPosition();
            if (focusOwner != null && focusOwner != this)
                focusOwner.RestoreCursorPosition();
        }
    }

    // запись происходит очевидным образом
    public void Write(string s) => Execute(() => Console.Write(s));
    public void WriteLine(string s) => Execute(() => Console.WriteLine(s));

    // чтение сложнее, делаем посимвольно
    public string ReadLine()
    {
        ConsoleEx oldFocus = Focus();
        try
        {
            StringBuilder line = new StringBuilder();
            int startX = currX, startY = currY;
            while (true)
            {
                // читаем нажатие без отображения
                var key = Console.ReadKey(intercept: true);
                lock (accessToken)
                {
                    // если фокус не наш, игнорируем
                    if (focusOwner != null && focusOwner != this)
                        continue;
                }
                // Enter -> заканчиваем ввод
                if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter)
                {
                    Execute(Console.WriteLine);
                    return line.ToString();
                }
                // Backspace -> уничтожаем предыдущий символ
                else if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.Backspace)
                {
                    if (line.Length == 0)
                        continue;
                    lock (accessToken)
                    {
                        line[line.Length - 1] = ' ';
                        Console.SetCursorPosition(startX, startY);
                        Console.Write(line.ToString());
                        line.Length--;
                        Console.SetCursorPosition(startX, startY);
                        Console.Write(line.ToString());
                        SaveCursorPosition();
                    }
                }
                // остальные символы выводим как есть
                else
                {
                    line.Append(key.KeyChar);
                    Execute(() => Console.Write(key.KeyChar));
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            SetFocus(oldFocus);
        }
    }

    public ConsoleEx Focus() => SetFocus(this);
    public void Unfocus() => SetFocus(null);

    public static ConsoleEx SetFocus(ConsoleEx k)
    {
        lock (accessToken)
        {
            var oldFocusOwner = focusOwner;
            focusOwner = k;
            focusOwner?.RestoreCursorPosition();
            return oldFocusOwner;
        }
    }
}
```

Ещё нужно бы сделать проверку на вертикальный скролл при вводе, и, вероятно, там же на непечатаемые символы.

Тестовый код:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ConsoleEx kin = new ConsoleEx(0, 0);
        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            ConsoleEx kout = new ConsoleEx(0, 10);
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                await Task.Delay(1000);
                kout.Write($"{i} ");
            }
        });
        var result = kin.ReadLine();
        kin.WriteLine($"You entered: {result}");
        kin.WriteLine("Press any key");
        Console.ReadKey(intercept: true);
    }
}
```

Результат:

[image: движущиеся картинки, вау!]

---

Альтернативный подход — ручное управление буфером консоли, как предлагается [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/741742/10105).

Comment: Я бы пошел через замену Console.Out и Console.Error.

Comment: Да и Console.In можно заменить.

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Хм. Если просто заменить `Console.Out`, то не получится использовать множественные экземпляры. А нам нужно, чтобы у каждого были свои координаты. И нужен фокус, без него выглядит так себе.