# Проблемы с созданием/отрисовкой объектов в консоли

Tags: c#, консоль

Игра. Существует объект танка, врага, пуля. Когда объектов нарисовано всех по 1, все более менее терпимо, но когда врагов становится больше и больше выстрелов, после объектов остается много "мусора", у меня сложилось впечатления что `Console.SetCursorPosition();` не успевает отрабатывать.
Для движения танка используется следующий код :

```
public void action(List<Enemies> eni)
{
    int x = this.x;
    int y = this.y;

    while (true)
    {
        switch (Console.ReadKey(true).Key)
        {
            case ConsoleKey.RightArrow:
                x = x < (int)Constants.MaxSizeField ? ++x : x;
                move('R', x, y);
                break;
            case ConsoleKey.LeftArrow:
                x = x == (int)Constants.MinSizeField ? x : --x;
                move('L', x, y);
                break;
            case ConsoleKey.DownArrow:
                y = y < (int)Constants.MaxSizeField ? ++y : y;
                move('D', x, y);
                break;
            case ConsoleKey.UpArrow:
                y = y == (int)Constants.MinSizeField ? y : --y;
                move('T', x, y);
                break;
            case ConsoleKey.Spacebar:
                if (direction != 'N')
                {
                    bullets.Add(new Bullet(this.x, this.y, direction));
                    aTimer.Start();
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

С танком проблем нет, за ним "мусора" не остается, проблемы с объектами, которые двигаются за счет таймера - пуля, враг.
Методы движение пули :

```
private void SetTimer()
{
    // Create a timer with a two second interval.
    aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(bulletSpeed);
    // Hook up the Elapsed event for the timer. 
    aTimer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
    aTimer.AutoReset = true;
    aTimer.Enabled = true;
}

private void OnTimedEvent(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    if (bullets.Count == 0)
    {
        aTimer.Stop();
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < bullets.Count; i++)
        {
            int x = bullets[i].X;
            int y = bullets[i].Y;

            if (y == 1)
            {
                bullets[i].destroy(x, y);
                bullets.Remove(bullets[i]);
            }
            else
            {
                bullets[i].shot(x, --y, 'S');

                for (int j = 0; j < ene.Count; j++)
                {
                    if (bullets[i].X >= ene[j].X && bullets[i].X <= ene[j].X + enemySize && bullets[i].Y >= ene[j].Y && bullets[i].Y <= ene[j].Y + enemySize)
                    {
                        bullets[i].destroy(bullets[i].X, bullets[i].Y);
                        bullets.Remove(bullets[i]);
                        ene[j].destroy(ene[j].X,ene[j].Y, ene[j].MaxSize);
                        ene[j].IsLive = false;
                        ene.Remove(ene[j]);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}   

public void shot(int x, int y, char direction)
{
    switch (direction)
    {
        case 'R':
            x = x + 3;
            y = y - 1;
            break;
        case 'L':
            x = x - 3;
            y = y - 1;
            break;
        case 'D':
            x = x + 2;
            break;
        case 'T':
            x = x + 2;
            y = y - 6;
            break;
    }

    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;

    Console.SetCursorPosition(x, y);
    Console.WriteLine("■");

    Console.SetCursorPosition(x, ++y);
    Console.WriteLine(" ");
}
```

Методы движения врага:

```
private void SetTimer()
{
    // Create a timer with a two second interval.
    timerForEnemies = new System.Timers.Timer(150);
    // Hook up the Elapsed event for the timer. 
    timerForEnemies.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
    timerForEnemies.AutoReset = true;
    timerForEnemies.Enabled = true;
}

private void OnTimedEvent(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.y < 40 && isLive)
    {
        int y = this.y++;
        move('D', x, y);
    }
    else
    {
        timerForEnemies.Stop();
        destroy(this.x, --this.y, this.MaxSize);
        isLive = false;
        Program.enemies.Remove(this);
    }
}  

public void move(char way, int x, int y)
{
    direction = way;

    drawFigure(x, y, symbol);

    if (way == 'R')
    {
        --x;
        for (int i = x; i < minSize + x; i++)
        {
            for (int j = y; j < maxSize + y; j++)
            {
                Console.SetCursorPosition(i, j);
                Console.WriteLine(" ");
            }
        }
    }

    if (way == 'L')
    {
        x = x + maxSize;
        for (int i = x; i < minSize + x; i++)
        {
            for (int j = y; j < maxSize + y; j++)
            {
                Console.SetCursorPosition(i, j);
                Console.WriteLine(" ");
            }
        }
    }

    if (way == 'T')
    {
        y = y + maxSize;
        for (int i = x; i < maxSize + x; i++)
        {
            for (int j = y; j < minSize + y; j++)
            {
                Console.SetCursorPosition(i, j);
                Console.WriteLine(" ");
            }
        }
    }

    if (way == 'D')
    {
        --y;
        for (int i = x; i < maxSize + x; i++)
        {
            for (int j = y; j < minSize + y; j++)
            {
                Console.SetCursorPosition(i, j);
                Console.WriteLine(" ");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Чем больше врагов и пуль тем ситуация хуже.
[image: Несколько примеров]

Подскажите пожалуйста путь решения проблемы. Это связано с таймерами?

Comment: У вас несколько таймеров, которые параллельно меняют состояние системы и параллельно пишут в консоль? мне кажется, что тут периодически при отрисовке фигуры (танчика, игрока, пули) - отрисовка может начаться когда фигура занимает одну позицию, и закончится когда фигура занимает уже другую позицию. ИМХО, таймер у вас должен быть один, и в событии таймера вы должны последовательно считывать ввод юзера,  пересчитывать состояние мира игры, и выводить его на экран. Именно последовательно, а не параллельно.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Как бы я рендерил в консоль:

1. Рендерил объекты, что в этот же момент не меняются. То есть игра становится однопоточной.
2. Рендерил только те символы, что изменились.

Как сделать первый пункт - очевидно. Как сделать второй - уже более интересно. Я бы абстрагировал весь вывод в консоль за свой класс. В классе бы хранил текущее состояние вывода в консоли и буфер, куда будут писать новое состояние. По итогу, при финальном рендере, я бы сранивал символ текущего состояния с тем, что в буфере, и если они отличаются - то тогда рендерим. То есть рендерить будем только те символы, что нужны нам для получения нужной картинки, и не более.
Но давайте перейдем к коду.

```
public class ConsoleWriter
{
    public readonly int Width;
    public readonly int Height;

    private Point[,] _activeBuffer;
    private Point[,] _activeView;

    public ConsoleWriter(int width, int height)
    {
        Width = width;
        Height = height;

        Console.SetWindowSize(width, height);

        _activeBuffer = new Point[width, height];
        _activeView = new Point[width, height];

        Clean(_activeBuffer);
        Clean(_activeView);
    }

    public void Flush()
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < Width; i++)
        {
            for (var j = 0; j < Height; j++)
            {
                var view = _activeView[i, j];
                var buff = _activeBuffer[i, j];

                if (!Equals(view, buff))
                {
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(i, j);
                    Console.ForegroundColor = buff.Color;
                    Console.Write(buff.Symb);
                }
            }
        }

        var temp = _activeBuffer;
        _activeBuffer = _activeView;
        _activeView = temp;

        Clean(_activeBuffer);
    }

    public void WriteText(int i, int j, string text, ConsoleColor color)
    {
        for (var ind = 0; ind < text.Length; ind++)
        {
            SetPoint(i + ind, j, color, text[ind]);
        }
    }

    public void SetPoint(int i, int j, ConsoleColor color, char symb)
    {
        if (i < 0 || i >= Width) return;
        if (j < 0 || j >= Height) return;

        _activeBuffer[i, j] = new Point(color, symb);
    }

    private void Clean(Point[,] view)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < Width; i++)
        {
            for (var j = 0; j < Height; j++)
            {
                view[i, j] = Point.Empty;
            }
        }
    }

    class Point
    {
        public static Point Empty = new Point(ConsoleColor.Black, ' ');

        public ConsoleColor Color { get; }
        public char Symb { get; }

        public Point(ConsoleColor color, char symb)
        {
            Color = color;
            Symb = symb;
        }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            return obj is Point point &&
                   Color == point.Color &&
                   Symb == point.Symb;
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            var hashCode = 286535306;
            hashCode = hashCode * -1521134295 + Color.GetHashCode();
            hashCode = hashCode * -1521134295 + Symb.GetHashCode();
            return hashCode;
        }
    }
}
```

Таким образом, у нас будет возможность писать в консоль и текст, и любые другие вещи. Например, заведем класс для игрока, который может двигаться по гризонтали

```
public class Player
{
    public int X { get; private set; }
    public int Y { get; }

    public Player(int x, int y)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }

    public void Move(int dx)
    {
        X += dx;
    }

    public void Draw(ConsoleWriter writer)
    {
        for (var i = -1; i <= 1; i++)
        {
            for (var j = -1; j <= 1; j++)
            {
                writer.SetPoint(i + X, j + Y, ConsoleColor.White, '■');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Класс противника, что двигается по вертикали

```
public class Enemy
{
    public int X { get; }
    public int Y { get; private set; }

    public Enemy(int x, int y)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }

    public void Move(int dy)
    {
        Y += dy;
    }

    public bool Shot(int x, int y)
    {
        if (Math.Abs(X - x) < 2 && Math.Abs(Y - y) < 2) return true;
        return false;
    }

    public void Draw(ConsoleWriter writer)
    {
        for (var i = -1; i <= 1; i++)
        {
            for (var j = -1; j <= 1; j++)
            {
                if (i != j && i != -j)
                    writer.SetPoint(i + X, j + Y, ConsoleColor.Red, 'E');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

И, наконец, класс для пули

```
public class Bullet
{
    public int X { get; }
    public int Y { get; private set; }

    public Bullet(int x, int y)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }

    public void Move(int dy)
    {
        Y += dy;
    }

    public void Draw(ConsoleWriter writer)
    {
        writer.SetPoint(X,  Y, ConsoleColor.Yellow, '^');
    }
}
```

Извиняюсь, дальше меня уже было не остановить. Итак, есть игрок, противник, пуля, метод рендера. Не хватает только игры. 
Насколько я могу помнить из своих поделок 20 летней давности, игра состоит из основного цикла, который по очереди считывает ввод юзера, обрабатывает логику игры и рендерит состояние. Отсюда родилась простенька идея класса игры:

```
public class Game
{
    private readonly ConsoleWriter _writer;
    private Player _player;
    private readonly Random _random = new Random();

    private List<Enemy> _enemies;
    private List<Bullet> _bullets;

    public Game(ConsoleWriter writer)
    {
        _writer = writer;
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        Startup();
        MainLoop();
    }

    private void Startup()
    {
        _player = new Player(60, 25);

        _enemies = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(x => CreateRandomEnemy())
            .ToList();

        _bullets = new List<Bullet>();
    }

    Enemy CreateRandomEnemy()
    {
        return new Enemy(_random.Next(0, _writer.Width), _random.Next(0, 5));
    }

    private void MainLoop()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (ReadInput()) return;
            var logic = GameLogic();

            if (logic is true)
            {
                _writer.WriteText(0, 0, "You win :)", ConsoleColor.White);
                _writer.Flush();
                return;
            }
            else if (logic is false)
            {
                _writer.WriteText(0, 0, "You lost :(", ConsoleColor.White);
                _writer.Flush();
                return;
            }

            Render();
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
    }

    private bool? GameLogic()
    {
        // двигаем противников вниз
        foreach (var enemy in _enemies)
        {
            enemy.Move(1);
        }
        // респаун тех противников, кто ушел за экран
        var before = _enemies.Count;
        _enemies.RemoveAll(e => e.Y > _writer.Height);
        var dlta = before - _enemies.Count;
        if (dlta > 0)
        {
            _enemies.AddRange(Enumerable.Range(0, dlta).Select(x=>CreateRandomEnemy()));
        }

        // двигаем пульки вверх
        foreach (var bullet in _bullets)
        {
            bullet.Move(-1);
        }
        _bullets.RemoveAll(e => e.Y < 0);


        // если пулька попала по противнику - убираем и пульку, и противника
        foreach (var enemy in _enemies.ToArray())
        {
            foreach (var bullet in _bullets.ToArray())
            {
                if (enemy.Shot(bullet.X, bullet.Y))
                {
                    _enemies.Remove(enemy);
                    _bullets.Remove(bullet);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        // если пулька попала по игроку - проигрыш
        if (_enemies.Any(enemy => enemy.Shot(_player.X, _player.Y)))
        {
            return false;
        }

        // Если противников не осталось - победа
        if (_enemies.Count == 0) return true;

        return null;
    }

    private bool ReadInput()
    {
        if (Console.KeyAvailable)
        {
            ConsoleKeyInfo key = Console.ReadKey(true);
            switch (key.Key)
            {
                case ConsoleKey.Escape:
                    return true;
                case ConsoleKey.LeftArrow:
                    _player.Move(-1);
                    break;
                case ConsoleKey.RightArrow:
                    _player.Move(1);
                    break;
                case ConsoleKey.Spacebar:
                    _bullets.Add(new Bullet(_player.X, _player.Y - 1));
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    private void Render()
    {
        foreach (var enemy in _enemies)
        {
            enemy.Draw(_writer);
        }

        foreach (var bullet in _bullets)
        {
            bullet.Draw(_writer);
        }

        _player.Draw(_writer);

        _writer.WriteText(0, 0, $"Enemies left {_enemies.Count}", ConsoleColor.Green);

        _writer.Flush();
    }
}
```

Насчет таймингов\алгоритмов я, конечно, не заморачивался.

Как запускать всю эту красоту:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var writer = new ConsoleWriter(120, 30);
        var game = new Game(writer);
        game.Run();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Итоговый результат:

[image: Итоговый результат]

Comment: Где научится так грамотно писать код?  И подскажите для чего пишут _ перед переменной?

Comment: @Winteriscoming >>для чего пишут _ перед переменной<< - Это префикс, указывающий на то что переменная является полем. Реже, происходит наоборот, _ указывает на то что переменная является аргументом функции или лямбды, и т.д. В общем, удобство.

Comment: ```Где научится так грамотно писать код?``` Больше практики, больше опыта, и будете писать код лучше меня. ```для чего пишут _ перед переменной``` - я так выделяю приватные поля класса.

Comment: @tym32167 извините за вопрос, а переопределенный метод `GetHashCode`, цифры в нем , это произвольный набор?

Comment: @Winteriscoming  Для меня это просто какие то большие числа :) Я использовал решарпер для генерации перегрузок (то есть я их не руками написал) для ```Equals``` и ```GetHashCode```, но перегрузка ```GetHashCode``` у меня нигде не используется. Видимо, решарпер посчитал что такой способ пересчета хеш кода будет оптимальным для минимизации количества коллизий. Но в данном случае это не имеет значения, так как, как я сказал, оно не используется нигде в коде.

Comment: @Winteriscoming и имейте ввиду, что мой код - просто черновик. Тут оч много мест для улучшений/оптимизаций, я просто хотел продемонстрировать идею, но меня захватило написать какой то работающий пример