# Управление консолью Windows

Tags: c#, c, windows, консоль

Где найти информацию по управлению консолью на с, с#? Не такое управление, чтобы поменять цвет, или размер, а полное. Например когда пишу игру, чтобы не очищать консоль полностью и отрисовывать заново карту, потому что получается не красиво, а обновить только пару символов. Или вот есть у меня список чисел от 1 до 10, размещённых каждое на новой строке, а пользователю нужно ввести сразу после этого числа какую-то строку. Или вот если программа вывела строку, её уже нельзя удалить и можно писать или после неё или на новой строке. Помню на с# есть метод для указания местоположения курсора, но этого сильно мало. В общем как писать крутые программы в консоли?)) В идеале, если вы скинете книгу, вдруг такую написали)

Comment: Гугль "C# curses". Там много всего.

Comment: Если под Windows, вам не обойтись без WinAPI.

Comment: А зачем обязательно консоль? Создайте винформу или окно wpf, поместите туда TextBox, задайте ему моноширинный шрифт и нужные цвета - сводобно-редактируемая консоль готова.

Comment: а я и не думал) Спасибо) но всё уже, я вот примерно час назад начал изучать операционные системы, а там и пойму, как устроены консоли)))

Comment: Dark Byte, и вам спасибо)) я и не думал, что такие библиотеки есть)))

Comment: Я тут как то уже отвечал на пдобный вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/741486/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B-%D1%81-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8/741742#741742

Answer (score -1):

могу ошибаться...
но, наверное лучший способ - сторонние библиотеки. Консоль отображает то что ваша программа пишет в файловый дескриптор. А этот дескриптор может быть стандартным - т.е. тот откуда читает cmd.exe или каким либо другим вами указанным файлом (в случае перенаправления вывода). и в этот файл можно писать чтото вроде тэгов, чтобы консоль показывала чтото необычное. Сам .net этого по моему не подразумевает, а писать парсер самому незапросто. Так что просто посоветую среди прочих  [libtcod](https://bitbucket.org/libtcod/libtcod/wiki/Features).