# Постоянная проверка элементов grid-a на условие и последующее выполнение метода для них

Tags: c#, wpf

Пишу мини-игру, опыта мало - жду критику :)
 использую сетку grid, суть игры: с неба падают блоки(блок - Rectangle в клетке сетки), наш персонаж находиться внизу, мы должны передвигать блоки, чтобы составить на земле ряд блоков(как в тетрисе).

Мой изначальный вариант - таймер, через определенное тиков спамит блоки, с каждым тиком блоки снижаются на сегмент(сектор, клетку) грида, персонаж работает вне таймера(падение запускается только после передвижения). Этот вариант явно не лучший, надо делать "падение" общим для блоков и персонажа.

Собственно, сама проблема: надо реализовать "падение" для блоков и персонажа, сами блоки падают вниз(сдвигаются вниз на одну клетку) через 180мс, сравнятся они через 8 тиков (timer.interval=180мс), персонаж двигается вне таймера, это значит, что его "падение" нужно запускать вне таймера(как я и сделал, и это являлось плохой идеей).

Была идея сделать уменьшить timer.interval до, например, 10мс, запускать падение для всех элементов грида - перебирать их всех в timer_tick, но блоки должны снижаться вниз на клетку через 180мс, а, так как, timer.interval = 10мс, то каждые 10мс будет запускаться "падение". Наверное надо как-то отмечать, что блок эмм... падает? или метод падения переписать?

тик таймера:

```
private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tick_num++;
        foreach (UIElement element in Sharp.Children)
        {
            if (element is Rectangle)
            {
                Falling(element);
            }
        }
        // time_for_block - кол-во тиков для спавна блока
        if (tick_num == time_for_block)
        {
            int block_Horizontal = random.Next(13);
            Draw_Block(block_Horizontal);// спавн блока
            tick_num = 0;
        }
    }
```

движение героя:

```
private void MainWindow_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (game_active)
        {
            switch (e.Key.ToString())
            {
                case "Up":
                    if (hero.vertical > 0)
                    {
                        step = (0, -1);
                        Move();

                    }
                    break;

                case "Left":
                    if (hero.horizontal > 0)
                    {
                        step = (-1, 0);
                        Move();
                    }
                    break;

                case "Right":
                    if (hero.horizontal < 12)
                    {
                        step = (1, 0);
                        Move();
                    }
                    break;

                case "Space":

                    break;
            }
        }
    }

private async void Move()
    {
        //step - передвижение героя, horizontal - по горизонтали, vertical - ...
        //moving_Block - блок в направлении движения героя
        Rectangle moving_Block = Get_Rectangle(hero.horizontal + step.horizontal, hero.vertical + step.vertical);
        //Block_Is_Free  - проверка блока на возможность его переместить
        if (moving_Block == null || Block_Is_Free(moving_Block))
        {
            if (moving_Block != null && Block_Is_Free(moving_Block))
                if (step.vertical == 0)
                {
                    Grid.SetColumn(moving_Block, hero.horizontal + (2 * step.horizontal));
                }

            Rectangle hero_View = Get_Rectangle(hero.horizontal, hero.vertical);

            hero.horizontal += step.horizontal;
            hero.vertical += step.vertical;

            Grid.SetRow(hero_View, hero.vertical);
            Grid.SetColumn(hero_View, hero.horizontal);
            //"падение" героя
            if (Down_Is_Clear(hero.horizontal, hero.vertical))
            {
                await Task.Delay(250);
                Hero_Falling(hero_View);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: не очень понял вопрос, но я [когда-то писал что то подобное](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/741486/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B-%D1%81-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8/741742#741742), только для консоли, мож пригодится

Comment: *надо делать "падение" общим для блоков и персонажа.* - персонажа надо двигать тоже по тику.

Comment: И какой тогда брать интервал для таймера? - минимальным, и когда (и как) запускать падение(интервал между сдвигом блоков вниз - 180мс)?