# Перемещение объектов. Консольное приложение

Tags: c#, разработка-игр, консоль

Проблема следующая: при старте приложения все объекты обновляются медленно. Если создать один объект с `stepTime = 50`, а другие с `stepTime = 1000`, то в начале они будут обновляться в одно и тоже время. 
Примерно через 30-50 секунд всё начинает работать отлично.
Хотелось бы понять как можно сделать нормальное обновление с самого начала. Важно то, что должны быть разные виды объектов с разным `stepTime`.

**Код обновления объектов**

```
    protected static void Run(){
        while(gameRunning){
            for(int i = 0; i < enemies.Count; i++){
                enemies[i].Move();
            }
        }
    }
```

**Код передвижения**

```
    public void Move(){
        if (!canMove || !CanMove(direction)) return;
        canMove = false;
        Task.Run(()=> MoveColdown());
        Global.map.Draw(new DrawData(this));
        position += direction;

    }

    public void MoveColdown(){
        Thread.Sleep(stepTime);
        canMove = true;
    }
```

**Код отрисовки**

```
   public void Draw(DrawData obj){
        IntVector2 pos = obj.position;
        IntVector2 dir = obj.direction;
        if (dir.x == 0 && dir.y == 0){
            Console.SetCursorPosition(pos.x, pos.y);
            Console.Write(obj.view);
        } else {
            Console.SetCursorPosition(pos.x, pos.y);
            Console.Write(obj.cellData);
            pos += dir;
            Console.SetCursorPosition(pos.x, pos.y);
            Console.Write(obj.view);
        }
    }
```

Comment: возможно вам будет интересно поглядеть на [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/741742/179763)

Comment: Да, спасибо, я уже прочитал до того, как написать свой пост. Это не то, что мне подходит.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не совсем понял чего именно вы хотите добиться, но вам явно не следует использовать `Thread.Sleep()`. Данный метод полностью останавливает текущий поток на указанное время. Советую почитать больше про асинхронное программирование в C#, а именно про ключевые слова *await* и *async*, а так же про метод `Task.Delay()` там всё достаточно просто.

Вместо строки `Task.Run(()=> MoveColdown());` я бы просто вызывал метод `MoveCooldown()` (разницы нет).
А метод `MoveCooldown()` я бы переписал следующим образом:

```
public async void MoveColdown()
{
    await Task.Delay(stepTime);
    canMove = true;
}
```

Советую также на будущее указывать тип приложения в тэгах (консольное, WPF, WinForms и т.д.), это упрощает жизнь отвечающим которые действительно могут ответить.

Также советую придерживаться правил форматирования кода, установленных Microsoft.

Comment: Ого. Вы действительно решили проблему! Я думал, что нет разницы между async функцией и вызовом через Task.Run.

Comment: Делаю что-то вот такое  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/StrikebyClaymore/godoProject/master/ConsoleApp1.gif

Comment: @ИванСоблазн Разницы то может быть и нет, но Thread.Sleep() обращается непосредственно к основному потоку, а в случае с консольным приложением без введения новых потоков - к единственному. Соответственно "усыпление" потока останавливает выполнение любого кода, в не зависимости от асинхронности.

Выглядит достаточно интересно, желаю удачи в реализации :)

Comment: @ИванСоблазн Не забудьте принять ответ если он вас устроил.