# Как делают "анимацию" в консоли?

Tags: java

Я бы хотел узнать,как создают такую некую анимацию в консоли, я видел даже игры в консолях, таже змейка.
Перерыл интернет,но до сих пор не понял,как все это делаеться?
Можно,ли на java все это сделать?

Comment: System.out.print через нужные промежутки времени да и всё

Comment: [Проблемы с созданием/отрисовкой объектов в консоли](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/741742/179763) - код на c#, но принцип тот же

Answer (score 4):

Консоль поддерживает специальные  [последовательности](http://www.climagic.org/mirrors/VT100_Escape_Codes.html), которые позволяют перемещать курсор, задавать цвет букв и фона. Если печатать из приложения эти последовательности, то можно реализовать графику в консоле.