# Как устранить повторение кода в начале и в конце методов?

Tags: c#, ооп, рефакторинг

Я создаю набор классов, элементов графического интерфейса, для небольшого консольного приложения.

Элементы представляют собой прямоугольники, текстовые поля и списки. Они могут быть показаны и скрыты с помощью методов, которые определены в общем интерфейсе элементов.

Элементы рисуют себя сами. Некоторые из них могут иметь цвет, так что при рисовании они изменяют цвет текста\фона в консоли. После рисования элемента нужно восстановить цвет консоли, который был до его рисования.

Методы рисования элементов стали повторять один и тот же код, чтобы выполнить восстановление цветов:

```
void Draw()
{
        //Сохраняем предыдущие цвета консоли.
        ConsoleColor oldForegroundColor = Console.ForegroundColor;
        ConsoleColor oldBackgroundColor = Console.BackgroundColor;
        
        //Устанавливаем свои цвета.
        //Рисуем что-то.

        //Восстанавливаем предыдущие цвета.
        Console.ForegroundColor = oldForegroundColor;
        Console.BackgroundColor = oldBackgroundColor;
}
```

Как избавится от повторения одного и того же кода в методах рисования? В классе может быть несколько методов рисования, у них могут быть разные сигнатуры.

Чтобы решить проблему, я заменял общий интерфейс элементов на абстрактный класс, который определял метод `Draw()`:

```
    abstract class GraphicalElement
    {
        public void Draw()
        {
            //Сохраняем предыдущие цвета консоли.
            ConsoleColor oldForegroundColor = Console.ForegroundColor;
            ConsoleColor oldBackgroundColor = Console.BackgroundColor;

            //Устанавливаем свои цвета и
            //рисуем что-то в этом методе.
            DoDraw();

            //Восстанавливаем предыдущие цвета.
            Console.ForegroundColor = oldForegroundColor;
            Console.BackgroundColor = oldBackgroundColor;

        }

        protected abstract void DoDraw();
    }
```

Но он оборачивал в код сохранения цвета только метод `DoDraw()`.

Элемент, отображающий список, при изменении списка должен обновляться. Использовать метод `Draw()` для этой задачи оказалось медленно, так как `Draw()` вызывает `DoDraw()`, который рисует весь список заново.
Я создал метод `DrawPartOfList(int drawBeginIndex)`, рисующий только часть списка, начиная с определенного элемента. Теперь его тоже нужно как-то обернуть в повторяющийся код.

Варианты, которые я могу предложить:

- Заменить `Draw()` в абстрактном классе на следующий метод:

```
    protected void DrawWithMethod(Action drawMethod)
    {
            //Сохраняем предыдущие цвета консоли.
            ConsoleColor oldForegroundColor = Console.ForegroundColor;
            ConsoleColor oldBackgroundColor = Console.BackgroundColor;

            drawMethod();

            //Восстанавливаем предыдущие цвета.
            Console.ForegroundColor = oldForegroundColor;
            Console.BackgroundColor = oldBackgroundColor;
    }
```

И использовать его вот так:

`DrawWithMethod(() => DrawPartOfList(drawBeginIndex));`

- Выделить методы рисования в отдельные классы. Все они будут реализовывать абстрактный класс:

```
    abstract class Painter
    {
        public void Paint()
        {
            //Сохраняем предыдущие цвета консоли.
            ConsoleColor oldForegroundColor = Console.ForegroundColor;
            ConsoleColor oldBackgroundColor = Console.BackgroundColor;

            DoPaint();

            //Восстанавливаем предыдущие цвета.
            Console.ForegroundColor = oldForegroundColor;
            Console.BackgroundColor = oldBackgroundColor;
        }

        protected abstract void DoPaint();
    }
```

Конкретные классы будут реализовывать `DoPaint()` и смогут добавить нужные для этого метода параметры, как свои поля:

```
    class ListPainter : Painter
    {
        private int paintBeginIndex;

        public ListPainter(int paintBeginIndex)
        {
            this.paintBeginIndex = paintBeginIndex;
        }

        protected override void DoPaint()
        {
            //Рисуем список, используя paintBeginIndex...
        }
    }
```

В коде графических элементов можно просто создавать объекты этих классов и использовать их:

```
Painter painter = new ListPainter(drawBeginIndex);
painter.Paint();
```

**Правка:** Я мог бы принять ответ, связанный с АОП.
Но мне стоило стоило задать вопрос именно об архитектуре программы, а не о моменте с повторениями кода. В приложении я последую совету @tym32167 в комментариях и создам абстрактный холст для рисования, оградив элементы от проблем консоли.

**Правка 2**: Я принимаю ответ @Alexander Petrov, связанный с АОП.
В приложении же я создал класс, представляющий холст по примеру класса `ConsoleWriter` [из ответа @tym32167](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/741742/179763). Созданный мною класс отличается только тем, что он хранит точки для обновления на холсте в `Dictionary<>`, по парам, состоящим из позиции точки и самой точки.  Благодаря этому удалось выполнять меньше итераций в методе `Flush()`, что еще больше увеличило скорость обновления вывода.

Comment: В конце вы пришли к решению проблемы?

Comment: _Использовать ... Draw() ... оказалось медленно_ - вы много раз в секунду обновляете консоль?

Comment: Как насчёт заюзать АОП+перехватчики (AOP+interceptors)? Правда, это снижает производительность. Но неужто вывод текста в консоли может быть проблемой?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, в Windows на самом деле жутко капризная и тормознутая консоль, а если часто дергать связанные с ней методы, ее производительность просаживается ещё больше. После MacOS/Linux'a на нее вообще смотреть физически больно :)

Comment: @Kir_Antipov - это да, даже когда пользуешься Git Bash в Винде, различие в скорости вывода заметно на глаз. Но что такого делает автор, что это становится существенно?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, dunno. Судя по описанию, он пытался разом напечатать очень большой список

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Первый раз при тестировании я сделал слишком большой список. Но потом уменьшил количество элементов до 20. В программе список может обновляться достаточно часто (например, пользователь часто удаляет\ добавляет элементы). При обновлении списка из 20 элементов раз в 1 секунду картинка заметно мигала.

Comment: > В конце вы пришли к решению проблемы? 
- Я не уверен в том насколько это хорошее решение.  

> Как насчёт заюзать АОП+перехватчики
- Находил ответы с упоминанием АОП на английском stackoverflow. Для АОП нужен фреймворк? К сожалению, мне нужно решение простом C#.

Comment: Да, АОП в C# внедряется только с помощью специальных фреймворков и/или постобработки сборки, на чистых шарпах такого нельзя (и хорошо, что нельзя)

Comment: У вас же проблемы со скоростью отрисовки, так почему каждый объект рисует себя напрямую в консоль? Зачем тратить время на установку цвета в консоли для каждого объекта? А Если объекты накладываются друг на друга - вы будете ратить время на прорисовку каждого из них? Абстрагируйте консоль от ваших фигур совсем, пусть фигуры рисуют сами себя в какой то абстрактный холст. И сделайте реализацию этого холста для консоли. И в реализацию вы можете добавить буфер и прочие вещи, которые не должны быть интересны фигурам. Почему вообще проблемы консоли волнуют ваши фигруы?

Comment: [Вот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/741742/179763) один то из моих старых примеров. Вы там увидите, что я даже не трачу время на прорисовку в консоль, если на определенной позиции уже нарисовано то, что мне нужно.

Comment: Вообще, для Винды кроме стандартной консоли есть множество других терминалов. Более удобных и быстрых. Если вы пишете приложение для себя или для своей организации, то установите такой альтернативный терминал (на всех компьютерах, где будет запускаться софтина). Это может кардинально решить проблему с медленным выводом.

Comment: @tym32167, кстати, скорость вашего примера можно ещё улучшить: оригинальный терминал винды тратит кучу времени на изменение цвета и установку курсора в нужное место. Так что без того, чтобы спускаться до WinAPI и дергать там отрисовку полноценного буфера, можно ещё добавить объединение участков одного цвета и их последовательный вывод

Comment: @Kir_Antipov там достаточно убрать thread.sleep и увидеть реальную скорость отрисовки. Мне вообще кажется, что автор зря на консоль грешит. Возможно, у автора проблема не с консолью, а с его архитектурой/кодом.

Comment: @tym32167, я именно про скорость отрисовки в ConsoleWriter, а так я ваш код даже не запускал :) "Возможно, у автора проблема не с консолью, а с его архитектурой/кодом" - как говорится, одно другого не исключает, скорее всего здесь имеют место обе проблемы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Одним из вариантов решения проблемы является АОП.
Оно бывает двух видов: compile-time и runtime.

Применим второй способ: создание перехватчика с помощью библиотеки [Unity.Interception](https://github.com/unitycontainer/unity).
Устанавливаем nuget-пакет.

Полный пример консольного приложения:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Unity.Interception;
using Unity.Interception.InterceptionBehaviors;
using Unity.Interception.Interceptors.InstanceInterceptors.InterfaceInterception;
using Unity.Interception.PolicyInjection.Pipeline;

namespace ConApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var graphicalElement = new GraphicalElement();

            var graphicalElementProxy = Intercept.ThroughProxy<IGraphicalElement>(
                graphicalElement, new InterfaceInterceptor(), new[] { new DrawBehavior() });

            Console.WriteLine("Start");

            // После вызова цвет вернётся к исходному
            graphicalElementProxy.Draw();

            Console.WriteLine("Middle");

            // Без прокси цвет не вернётся к исходному
            graphicalElement.Draw();

            Console.WriteLine("End");
        }
    }

    public interface IGraphicalElement
    {
        void Draw();
    }

    public class GraphicalElement : IGraphicalElement
    {
        public void Draw()
        {
            // Рисуем что-то в этом методе
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
            Console.WriteLine("Test Draw");
        }
    }

    public class DrawBehavior : IInterceptionBehavior
    {
        public bool WillExecute => true;

        public IEnumerable<Type> GetRequiredInterfaces() => Type.EmptyTypes;

        public IMethodReturn Invoke(IMethodInvocation input, GetNextInterceptionBehaviorDelegate getNext)
        {
            // Перед вызовом метода на исходном целевом объекте
            // Сохраняем предыдущие цвета консоли
            ConsoleColor oldForegroundColor = Console.ForegroundColor;
            ConsoleColor oldBackgroundColor = Console.BackgroundColor;

            var result = getNext()(input, getNext);

            // После вызова метода на исходном целевом объекте
            // Восстанавливаем предыдущие цвета
            Console.ForegroundColor = oldForegroundColor;
            Console.BackgroundColor = oldBackgroundColor;

            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Методы, которые будем перехватывать, вынесены в интерфейс.

В классе-перехватчике `DrawBehavior` реализуем дополнительные действия, выполняемые до и после вызова перехватываемого метода.

Создаём прокси с помощью `Intercept.ThroughProxy` и далее используем его.

Аналогично можно создавать прокси для любых классов, реализующих данный интерфейс.

---

Прокси-объекты создаются с помощью рефлексии, поэтому производительность кода, естественно, снижается.

Есть и другие runtime-библиотеки: Castle Dynamic Proxy, Spring.NET и пр.

Использование compile-time AOP может дать большую производительность. Но там есть свои проблемы.

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать `doDraw` лямбдой, аргументом `SavingDraw`.

Сама `SavingDraw` сохранит и восстановит состояние консоли, а в середине запустит `doDraw`.

`SavingDraw` сделать где-то в "утилитах", тогда наследования можно избежать, и вызывать ее гибко отовсюду, любое количество раз.

Еще предусмотреть try-finally вокруг вызова `doDraw`.

Comment: ` Util.SavingDraw(()=>{  ...  })`